# Is there any chance to get caret index from TextBoxBase?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i get caret index from TextBoxBase?I am creating listener for editor,but i dont have any information about this editor,i can get only TextBoxBase.
[EDIT] I use WPF

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, or WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: @JavidanGuliyev Is the TextBoxBase derivative you're using a 3rd party or custom control, or is it just that it can be RichTextBox or TextBox at runtime?

Comment: yes it can be any of them,i can only handle textBoxBase

Comment: it can be any editor,but not custom

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows Forms `TextBoxBase`, you can use [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx).

If you're dealing with WPF or Silverlight, there is unfortunately no direct way to handle this from the base class, as the selection information is handled by the derived classes, as different classes handle it very differently.

For example, [`TextBox.SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart.aspx) would give you the appropriate point for a `TextBox`, but if you had a `RichTextBox`, you'd need to look at the [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection.aspx).[`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.start.aspx) property explicitly, as it's handled in a separate class.